# Login and get information user with token in spring (no OAuth)

Tags: spring, spring-security, restful-authentication

I am implementing a project RESTful API, it should login (username / password) and returns a token, I want to use token to retrieve user information.

I follow the instructions:
https://github.com/virgo47/restful-spring-security

But: I do not know how to use it in my function, you can help me with?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseObject<Object> login(
        @RequestParam(value = "username", required = true) String username,
        @RequestParam(value = "password", required = true) String password,
        @RequestHeader(value = "token") String token,
        HttpSession session) {
    //TODO

    return new ResponseObject<Object>(1, "Success", data);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseObject<User> getInfo(@RequestHeader(value = "token", required = true) String token,
        HttpSession session) {
    //TODO
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that ? Why not just get the logged in user from the SecurityContext as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test() {
    System.out.println(" *** MainRestController.test");
    // Spring Security dependency is unwanted in controller, typically some
    // @Component (UserContext) hides it.
    // Not that we don't use Spring Security annotations anyway...
    return "SecurityContext: "
            + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                    .getName();
}
```

If you insist on doing it, you can do the following.

```
UserDetails userDetails =
 (UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
tokenManager.getUserTokens(userDetails)
```